Automation when selecting which sheet will be loaded
I want to load all the files and folders in My Drive into a Google spreadsheet. If that spreadsheet does not exist, it has to be created. If it does, a new sheet on the spreadsheet has to be created. Each sheet must be named by the date and time it was created. The function to create or amend the spreadsheet is the following:
// Function to create or amend the spreadsheet
function createOrAmend() {

  var ss=DriveApp.getFilesByName('MV_DriveListing');
  
  // Conditions
  // Case 1: MV_DriveListing does not exist. In that case, create it.
  

  if (ss.hasNext()==false){
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.create('MV_DriveListing');
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
    var mySS=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet=mySS.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.setName(formattedDatetime);
    // Array of header values
    var headArray=['DT Written','ID','Name','Type','Size (bytes)','MIME Type',
                   'Path','DT Created','DT Modified'];
    // FOR loop to fill in the array with the values
    for (var i=0;i<headArray.length;i++){
      // Set ranges
      var header=sheet.getRange(1,i+1,1,1);
      header.setValue(headArray[i]);
        }

    // Freeze top row
    sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
    // Make font style bold, background colour yellow, and set a border
    // around the header with a medium-solid line.
    var header=sheet.getRange(1,1,1,9);
    header.setFontWeight('bold')
          .setBackground('yellow')
          .setBorder(true,true,true,true,null,null,null,
                     SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
  

 
    // Move spreadsheet to /My Drive/Drive Listing.
    // If "Drive Listing" folder does not exist, please
    // create it or choose another destination.
    var ssID=mySS.getId();
 // Logger.log('ID'+ssID);
    var myFile=DriveApp.getFileById(ssID);
    var target=DriveApp.getFolderById('16QGUPg9fXlxVvXcK_QixFdcaEuJ0-fhw'); // Replace this ID with the ID of the desired location.
    myFile.moveTo(target);
    }
    

  // Case 2: MV_DriveListing exists. In that case, duplicate 
  // the active sheet, and delete (clear) the data area.
  else {
     var ss=SpreadsheetApp.open(ss.next());
     SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
     var mySS=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     mySS.getActiveSheet();
     var sheet=mySS.duplicateActiveSheet();
     sheet.activate();
     sheet.setName(formattedDatetime);
     
     //Clear data range
     var dataRange=sheet.getRange('A2:I');
     dataRange.clear();
  }

  // Call the function to load files and folders
  //loadFiles();
}


As you see, the calling of the function to load the files is in a comment. This needs to be changed.
The functions to load the files and folders are the following:
// Load files
function loadFiles(){
  var ss=DriveApp.getFilesByName('MV_DriveListing');
  var ssNext=SpreadsheetApp.open(ss.next());
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ssNext);
  var mySS=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=mySS.getSheetByName('23/09/2024 09:03:17');
  //Logger.log('fileProperty='+fileProperty);

  
  // Get last non-empty row
  var lastRow=sheet.getRange(1,1)
                         .getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)
                         .getRow();
  Logger.log('Last Row='+lastRow);
  
  //Get the files
  if (fileProperty==null){
    var files=DriveApp.searchFiles("'me' in owners");
    var count=1;
  }
  else {
    var files=DriveApp.continueFileIterator(fileProperty);
    
  }
    var count=lastRow;

  // Continuation Tokens for the files
  
  
  // WHILE loop
  while (files.hasNext()){
    count++;
    var file=files.next();
    // Parents of files
    var parents=file.getParents().next();
    if (parents=='My Drive'){
      var path='/'+parents;
    }
    else {
      var path='/My Drive/'+parents;
    }

    var dataArray=[formattedDatetime,file.getId(),file.getName(),'File',
                   file.getSize(),file.getMimeType(),
                   path,
                   file.getDateCreated(),file.getLastUpdated()];
    // FOR loop
    for (var i=0;i<9;i++){
      // Load files
      var range=sheet.getRange(count,i+1,1,1);
      range.setValue(dataArray[i]); 
      }
    // Continuation token and property
      var fileCont=files.getContinuationToken();
      properties.setProperty('fileProperty',JSON.stringify(fileCont));
      var fileProperty=properties.getProperty('fileProperty');
      //Logger.log('fileProperty='+fileProperty);
      
  }
  properties.deleteProperty('fileProperty');
  loadFolders();
}
  
function loadFolders(){ 
  var ss=DriveApp.getFilesByName('MV_DriveListing');
  var ssNext=SpreadsheetApp.open(ss.next());
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ssNext);
  var mySS=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=mySS.getSheetByName('23/09/2024 09:03:17');
  //Logger.log('fileProperty='+fileProperty);
  // Get the folders
  if (folderProperty==null){
    var folders=DriveApp.searchFolders("'me' in owners");
  }
  else {
    var folders=DriveApp.continueFolderIterator(folderProperty);
  }
  // Last non-empty row
  var lastRow=sheet.getRange(1,1)
                   .getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)
                   .getRow();
  Logger.log('Last Row='+lastRow);
  var count=lastRow;

  // WHILE loop
  while (folders.hasNext()){
     count++;
     var folder=folders.next();
     // parents of a folder
     var parents=folder.getParents().next();
     if (parents=='My Drive'){
       var path='/'+parents;
     }
     else {
       var path='/My Drive/'+parents;
     }

     var dataArray=[formattedDatetime,folder.getId(),folder.getName(),'Folder',
                    folder.getSize(),'N/A',path,
                    folder.getDateCreated(),folder.getLastUpdated()];
  // FOR loop
     for (var i=0;i<9;i++){
       var range=sheet.getRange(count,i+1,1,1);
       range.setValue(dataArray[i]);
     }
     var folderCont=folders.getContinuationToken();
     properties.setProperty('folderProperty',JSON.stringify(folderCont));
     var folderProperty=properties.getProperty('folderProperty'); 
    // Logger.log('folderProperty='+folderProperty);
   }

   properties.deleteProperty('folderProperty');  
}

As you can see, the name of the desired sheet is hardcoded in the getSheetByName() method. In every loading, I always have to run the createOrAmend() function, then manually change the name (date and time) in the loadFiles() and loadFolders() functions, and then run the loadFiles() function (which automatically calls loadFolders() in the end).
I want to change it, so that createOrAmend() can call loadFiles() automatically, and automatically tell it which sheet should be loaded. I have not yet found a way to do it. Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?
I tried creating a variable of the sheet name in the createOrAmend() function, but of course it is not recognised outside the function.

This post is too long. Please add summary/Tl/Dr at the top of the question to make it clear what the specific programming problem is to be solved. It might be a good idea to include a [mcve] for that particular problem.

Note: The code uses the variable name for two different types of objects: a file iterator and a spreadsheet. It's better to use a different variable name for each object type.

I  would recurse through the drive to do this.

I want to load all the files and folders in My Drive into a Google spreadsheet. This seems ambiguous and I'm not sure what this means. At first I thought that you wanted to import the contents of all your files and folders into a spreadsheet (unusual but possible, I suppose). But I think you just mean that you want to create a listing of every file and folder. Or perhaps it is something else. One might say that the code shows exactly what you are trying to do, but this should be spelt out in the body of the question. Would you please clarify this?

No worries Tedinoz, I solved it. But thanks for your suggestions, I should have included only the relevant code.

I solved it Well done. Why not post an answer to your own question? It may be useful  for future users AND it will be tagged with an answer so that users know that the question has a solution. Plus, it's a rewarding thing - paying it forward for other users.
